# R parallel package: find children?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

What is the parallel equivalent to "multicore::children" in parallel?

As far as I can tell, there is none. The use case would be something like:

```
while(T){
   parallel(some_long_process)
   mccollect(wait=F)
   # If we are using 10 cores or more stop
   while((num_cores_used<-parallel::children())>=10){
      Sys.sleep(60)
      mccollect(wait=F) # Clear the children
   }
}
```

Comment: Aside this question, don't use `T` and `F`. Use `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

Comment: I'm actually not sure why?

Comment: In case of `T <- FALSE`. Or `T <- 1e10`. `TRUE` and `FALSE` are protected. Not `T` and `F`.

Comment: Oh I see, I guess you're right as I just tried assigning to "TRUE" and its rightly restricted.

Answer (score 2):

It's still there, but no longer exported. You can use it by calling `parallel:::children()`, but there's no guarantee it will remain there in future versions nor that its behaviour won't change since it's not exported.

Comment: Also, if you call an unexported function such as `children` in your own package, your package won't be accepted into CRAN. There are many functions that were exported by `multicore` and `snow` that are not exported by `parallel`.

Comment: Thanks. Okay, well I guess the question is what bad behavior does it present to use children() that the author decided not to export it?

Comment: I think with the move to the `parallel` package there was a feeling people should be using the high level parallelisation functions only.